# VS Code Snippets too greedy with dot character

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-snippets

I have the following snippet configured.

```
{
"Pandas Display All Columns": {
    "scope": "python",
    "prefix": "pd.options.display.max_columns",
    "body": [
        "pd.options.display.max_columns = None"
    ],
    "description": "Allows all columns of the dataframe to print"
}
```

The problem is every time I type a period `.` and hit enter it auto-completes with this snippet.  For example if I'm typing a doc string and use a period and hit enter.  I know, I know... working as designed.

If I shorten the prefix so it does not contain and dot character `.` so only `pd` is used, it is not intuitive when the intellisense pops up. How do you suggest I formulate my snippet so it is intuitive and not showing every time I type `.` all by itself?